# Method for Sorting a list of expense categories into specific categories

Tags: python, sql

I am new with SQL/Python.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to sort or categorize expense items into three primary categories.

That is I have a 56,000 row list with about 100+ different expense categories. They vary from things like Payroll, Credit Card Pmt, telephone, etc.

I would like to put them into three categories, for the sake of analysis.

I know I could do a GIANT IF statement in Excel, but that would be really time consuming, based on the fact that there are 100+ sub categories.

Is there any way to expedite the process with Python or even in Excel?

Also, I don't know if this is material or not, but I am preparing this file to be uploaded to a SQL database.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking to parse an Excel file and insert the parsed contents in to a DB?

Comment: File format xls or xlsx?

Comment: Depending on your categorisation logic; You *can* do it in Excel with a ***short*** `VLOOKUP` instead of a ***giant*** `IF`, or even use VBA and code your own function.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table called something like ExpenseCategories, with the columns ExpenseCategory, PrimaryCategory.

This table would have one row for each expense category (which you can enforce with a constraint if you like).  You would then join this table with your existing data in SQL.

By the way, in Excel, you could do this with a vlookup() rather than an if().  The vlookup() is analogous to using a lookup table in SQL.  The equivalent of an if() would be a giant case statement, which is another possibility.